# "インストール方法を知りたい" 質問に含めて欲しい情報は何ですか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, クローズ理由

特定のソフトウェアやライブラリ、プラグインがインストールできないので「インストール方法を教えてください」という質問をしたいとき、一般にどういう情報があると良いですか？
どういう指針で情報を羅列すると解決が早くなるでしょうか。

具体的には、先日「[Visual Studio に pydicom をインストールする方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61465/19110)」という質問が「より詳細な情報、もしくは明確さが必要」としてクローズされたのですが、どんな情報が追記されれば再オープンに繋がるでしょうか？　このご質問はクローズ時、

- Visual StudioにPythonはインストールしている。
- pydicomを利用したいがインストールの仕方が分からない。

という情報のみでした。他にどんな情報が必要だったでしょうか。

<sub>※一般論と具体例を混ぜこぜにしていますが、具体例の方を見て一般論が知りたくなったという流れなので、最終的には一般論が明文化できれば良いな、と思っています。</sub>

Comment: メモ：皆さんの回答を見ていて、今回わたしはこの質問を「質問者目線だと何をすればもっと良かった？」という形で問いましたが、逆に「回答者目線だとどう行動すれば良かった？　どうコメントすれば良かった？」という形で問うこともできると気付きました。これは別の質問として投稿できるかもしれません。

Answer (score 4):

回答ではないですが、クローズ投票こそしなかったものの、思うところがあったので、記しておきます。

**Visual Studio に pydicom をインストールする方法**

というタイトルがそもそもおかしいです。Visual Studioに`pydicom`はインストールできません。「Visual Studioから呼び出せるように設定されたPythonに`pydicom`をインストール」したいのだと解釈しました。（Pythonにインストールも正確には違うかもしれませんが…）

些細な表現の問題と捉えることもできるかもしれませんが、他方で、問題の本質を見抜けていない・質問者自身がやりたいことを理解できていない、とも捉えることができます。曖昧な質問としてクローズされたのはこの辺りにあったのではないかと思います。

[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) より

> #### 具体的な問題をまとめたタイトルを書く
>
> - 問題をまとめることが難しい場合は、**タイトルは最後に書きます**。質問の残りの部分を先に書いたほうが、問題を説明しやすくなることもあります。

とありますが、曖昧な質問に多く見られる

- まずタイトルを書き
- タイトルの補足を本文に書く

を地で行っているように見受けられます。「他にどんな情報が必要だった」かどうか以前の問題として、「質問をする」という質問者としての責務が果たされていない・アドバイスをしたとして果たされると見込みづらい、という状況だったのではないかと思います。（ので、誰もアドバイスせずクローズされてしまったのかと。）

Answer (score 3):

スタック・オーバーフローはコミュニティによる助け合いの場なので、分からない事があっても
ある程度の "自助努力" は必要だと思います。
(疑問を下調べせず回答を求めていると、回答側がコンシェルジュや御用聞きになってしまいます)

ヘルプや行動規範にも記載のある通り「よくわからない」だけでは残念ながら他人への説明になりません。

#### [質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

> **問題をきちんと説明する**
>
> - 「うまくいかない」だけでは問題を説明したことになりません。

#### [行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

> **助けを求めてここに来た場合には、他の人があなたを手助けしやすいよう気を配りましょう。**
>   ガイドラインに従いましょう。そして私たちのコミュニティはボランティアの支えによって
>   存在していることを忘れないでおきましょう。

まともなツールであればインストール手順が用意されているはずなので、まずマニュアルの存在は確認したのか、実際にインストール作業は試してみたのか、辺りの情報が必要になってくると思います。

「マニュアルが英語で書かれてて分からない」等であれば、それをそのまま書いてもらえば十分な気がします。分からないことがあるのは構わないので、がんばってその"分からない"を説明して欲しいなというのが率直な感想です。

ヘルプの「[ごまかさない、正直であれ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)」はそういうことを指しているんじゃないかなと。

Answer (score 2):

全てが必要と言うわけでは無いですが、これらがあるとピンポイントで答えを作ることが楽になるでしょう。

- 使っているVisual Studioの版数 : 2013以前/2015/2017/2019
  [Windows に Visual Studio の Python サポートをインストールする方法](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
- 使っている/使おうとしているPythonインタープリタと版数/bit環境 : Python/Anaconda(/IronPython/PyPy/Jython/他?)
  [Python インタープリターのインストール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/python/installing-python-interpreters?view=vs-2019)
- 使っている/使おうとしているPython環境 : グローバル環境/仮想環境/conda環境
  [Visual Studio で Python 環境を作成および管理する方法](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
- 該当環境の他のモジュールは更新されているか
  [Python 環境 ウィンドウ タブ リファレンス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/python/python-environments-window-tab-reference?view=vs-2019)

なお、conda環境(=AnacondaのPackages(conda))ではデフォルトのサーチパスでpydicomは見つからなかったので、サーチパスを追加するかインタプリタや環境を変える作業が必要そうです。

---

Pythonでは何のインタプリタ(素のCPython/Anaconda/他)を使っているかが最初の分かれ目ですね。
対応するパッケージ管理のツールが何(PyPI(pip)/conda)かで最初の手順が変わります。

Visual StudioでPythonだと、一応以下のページを紹介するだけでもその先を自力で推測してたどっていける人には役に立つのですが、知らなかった人はそのメニューで何をすればいいかも悩むところでしょうし、このページにはAnacondaでの情報は無いのでAnaconda系の人はさらに悩むでしょう。
[手順 5: Python 環境へのパッケージのインストール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019)

回答のために調べたりする側は、この「Python環境」ウインドウに表示されている環境で、そのうちの何を使っているかの情報があれば、調査/考慮範囲が絞れるのでやりやすいでしょう。

情報追加のアドバイスもVisual Studioの何処からどういう情報を取ってきて追記するかが具体的(かつ簡単)ならば質問者さんも対処しやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。具体的に何があったら便利だったかを知ることができました。では、回答を知らない前提で、どういう風に考えたらこれらの情報を前もって追加できていたと思われますか？　回答を知っていればこういう情報が必要なのは目に見えていそうですが、回答を知らない段階で「この情報が必要だ」と言うのは難しいです。どういう指針で情報を追加すれば良かったのかなあ、というところが分かると次また質問するときに便利なので、できればそこも明らかにしたいです。