# 質問「何をする関数なのか分からない」は何をすれば良くなりますか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

昨日投稿されたご質問「[何をする関数なのか分からない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62345/19110)」に、たくさんマイナス票がついているのを発見しました。現状合計 -4 となっています。

しかし、コメント欄には特にどこを改善すれば良いのかの指摘が無く、質問者さんにとっても何がマイナスなのか分かりにくい状況になっていると感じます。

個人的には初心者の方がこういう質問をするのは合点がいきますし、プラス投票しにくくてもマイナス投票する程では無いかと思っていました。

このご質問はどのような点を改善すべきでしょうか。今後新しく質問する際の指針として、気を付けると「良い質問」になるキーポイントは何でしょうか。

また、もし何かしら回答を改善するコメントをするとすれば、どういったものになるでしょうか。

関連

- [学校の宿題は回答するべきでしょうか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/19110)
- [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/257670)

Answer (score 5):

**問題が十分に絞り込まれていない**、または**問題に対する取り組みが明らかではない**から、という理由が考えられます。以下の二項目では、前者の文章は一見して単純ですが、後者よりも網羅的な解説が求められます。なぜなら、質問者が躓いている箇所が明らかになっていないからです。

- 「この関数が行う処理を教えてください」
- 「この関数はこのように動作するので、こういった結果になると思いましたが、実際はこのような結果になりました」

問題が明確になっていればそこに焦点を当てた回答が行えますが、そうでなければ全体をカバーした回答をする必要があります。もし網羅的な説明をしたとしても、質問者が躓いた箇所の疑問に答えられているかは保証されません。

この問題を改善するためには、質問文に書かれている**「自分の考え」の根拠を書く**と良いのではないかと思います。これにより、回答者は問題となっている箇所の解説を重点的に行え、タイトルをより具体的な内容に改善することも出来ます。また、現状では質問者が問題に対して行った取り組みも明らかになっていませんが、推測の根拠を書くことでこれも補えると思います。

Comment: 「自分の考えの根拠を書く」というのは端的で分かりやすいですね！　今回の質問者さんの場合与えられた関数の挙動を確認する（たとえば、なにかしら出力する）のもハードルがあったのではないかと思っていて、となると「プログラムを読んでなんとなく」とか「前後の問題の雰囲気から」とかいった理由になるのかもな、と思いました。仮にそのようなものであったとしても理由があった方が回答するときの参考になるし、むしろ無いとやや困るというのは同意です。

Answer (score 4):

[“インストール方法を知りたい” 質問に含めて欲しい情報は何ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3162/4236) と同じ印象を受けました。

タイトルの「何をする関数なのか分からない」は完全に投稿者の感想でしかなく、質問の体をしていません。この時点で、一方的に書き込み自分だけが解決できればそれでいい、質問者としてQ&Aの蓄積に貢献する気がない、ように見受けられます。
案の定、次の投稿のタイトルが「[何をする関数なのかわからない　２](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/62349/1)」です。

改善提案以前の問題として、質問者としてコミュニティに参加するのであれば、[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)をよく読んでもらうほかないと思います。

[pythonの問題がわかりません答えを教えてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62462/4236) なんかもやはり同じ問題だと思います。アドバイスをしたところで質問者は書き捨てて逃げるだけです。

Comment: 「良い質問をするには？」へ案内するのは賛成です。タイトルに関しては、質問者さんが感じている疑問は確かに「何をする関数なのか分からない」というものであり、今回はこれで良かったのではと私は思っています。もっと詳しく、たとえば「ポインタを使った関数の挙動が分からない」みたくすることもできたかもしれませんが、質問者さんのレベルで最初からそこまで書けるべきかは疑問です（後からコメント等でフォローアップしてタイトル編集に繋げるべきだったかもしれません）。なお後続の質問については私も改善して欲しくて、以前コメントを残しておきました。

Answer (score 2):

「課題を質問しているからダメ」というつもりはありませんが、元が課題だろうと第三者に説明するなら **自分自身が書いたものとして** 質問内容を説明する必要があると思います。

類似サービスの teratail にもポイントがまとめられています。

[質問するときのヒント | teratail](https://teratail.com/help/question-tips)

掻い摘んで抜粋すると:

> - 自分で何が分からないのか把握する
> - タイトルには要件を書く
> - 実際の結果を書く(自分で試す)
> - 期待する結果を書く

また、たとえ課題に対する質問でも、評価が高い過去の投稿を見てみると、「入力」「現状での出力」「期待する結果」「ソースコード」など一通り必要な情報が網羅されています。

[C++でスペースを出力したいところ、替わりに数字の32が出力される](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/14443)